# Wordpress category, get all its posts

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am currently finish of my theme for a wordpress website that I am building, I am having a problem getting my categories to work though.

I am lost as to how I can loop through the current category if I am at a URL of say "/category/category-name" how would I loop the posts that belong to the category "category name".

I I do the following on my template

`<p>Category: <?php single_cat_title(); ?></p>` I get the following output

> Category Name

So how do I loop through that categories posts?

**Category.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 
    <article class="content">   
        <section class="top">       
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>         

            <?php endwhile; else: ?>        
                 <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>      
            <?php endif; ?>
        </section>  
        <section class="middle">        
        </section> 
     </article> 
     <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**page-news.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<article id="content">
    <section class="top">
        <?php query_posts('post_type=news'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <section class="news">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <h2><?php echo strtolower(the_title()); ?></h2>
                <span class="posted"><?php the_date("l jS M Y"); ?></span>
                <?php 
                    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
                    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
                ?>
                <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($content), 0, 400).'…' ; ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read_more">Read More</a></p>
                <p class="tags">
                    <strong>Categories:</strong>
                    <?php
                    $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
                    $cats = array();

                    foreach($post_categories as $c){
                        $cat = get_category( $c );
                        $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php foreach($cats as $k => $v) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $cats[$k]['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $cats[$k]['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>                    
                </p>
                <p class="tags">
                    <strong>Tags: </strong>
                    <?php $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID); ?>
                    <?php foreach ($tags as $tag) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $tag->slug; ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </p>
            </section>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php get_sidebar('news'); ?>
    </section>
    <section class="middle">

    </section>
</article>
```

So page-news.php are where my news article reside, and the user can get the category using the link generated by `<a href="<?php echo $cats[$k]['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $cats[$k]['name']; ?></a>`

Comment: What's the filename of the template file?  If it's `category.php` then the posts belonging to the category are already loaded, and you would just loop through them.

Comment: it is category.php, am I right in thinking I can just do the following now?

`<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

Comment: seems strange then that is coming back as having no posts then...

Comment: (1) are you sure you have posts in the category and (2) are you sure that the template you're editing is the on that is being used? (Add "This is my template" at the top to check the latter.

Comment: definatly the correct template, as my loop reverts to, "sorry no post", and there are definatly posts in the category as I getting to the page through a category link in a post

Comment: Can you post your template code in full?

Comment: Please see edited question for template code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're outputting anything in `category.php` based on the code above.  `the_post()` doesn't echo anything.  It just puts the next record into `$post`. Try this...

```
<?php
get_header();
$cat = get_category(get_query_var("cat"));
var_dump($cat); //make sure that there really is a valid category and it's the right one
?>

<h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $cat->name?></h1>
<?php 
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()){
        the_post();
        <h2><?php the_title()?></h2>
        <?php the_content()?>
      <?php
      }
} else {
    ?>
    <p>No posts found!</p>
   <?php
}
?>


<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

In `page-news.php` you should probably consider using `the_category()` to echo out the category links rather than constructing the links yourself -- that way you'll know that the links are valid....

```
<p class="tags"><?php the_category()?></p>
```

Comment: so it is definatly a valid category, and the category definatly has posts in it, as in the admin area I can see next to the category that there is 1 news article, however when in category.php there are posts

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) inside your [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) to loop the posts