# Display all the posts from category

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a category.php with script inside:

```
<?php $categories = get_the_category(); ?>
          <?php  $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID; ?>
          <?php  query_posts('cat='.$category_id); ?>
          <?php while (have_posts()) : ;?>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                        <div class="article">           
                          <div class="article_image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">                      
                            <i class="fa article_favourite"><?php wpfp_link() ?></i>
                          </div>
                          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" id="half_height_link"></a>   
                          <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                          <div class="article_subheading_wrapper">
                            <p> 
                             <!--Cut the long text -->          
                              <?php                  
                                $string = substr(get_field("subheading"), 0, 100);
                                echo $string."… "; 
                              ?>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <ul>
                              <li><p id="views"><img id="eye" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/icons/watched_icon.svg"> <span><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></span></p></li>
                              <li><p id="likes"><i class="fa"></i><?php if(function_exists('like_counter_p')) { like_counter_p(''); }
                      ?></p></li>
                              <li><p id="comments"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></p></li>
                            </ul>       
                        </div>                    
                      </div>
                <?php endif; ?>                   
          <?php  endwhile; ?>
```

It supposed to be displaying all the posts that belong to this category. I does, but it displays only recent one and infinite number of times.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: what is the `have_posts()` method ? what does it return?

Comment: Found easier solution here [Wordpress category, get all its posts][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912572/wordpress-category-get-all-its-posts?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE, don't use `query_posts`, it is evil. Rather use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 1):

Try either of this,

```
get_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=-1');

or 

query_posts( array ( 'cat' => cat_id, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

Hope this helps you